# Can i add coutom badges in wix. Without wix badges app?

Tags: velo

have coded a login page that redirects every user to the same dashboard page. Each user will have badges assigned by an 'administrator' (they won't have access to wix so I can't use the Wix Assign Badges tool) which gives them permission to access certain pages on the backend effectively giving each user a permission to do certain things.

I have a dynamic item page for each user and need a way to assign/remove a badge from the user's account. Anybody with the 'administrator' badge can access the dynamic item page to update a member's badges and details.

The dynamic page needs a repeater type thing of all the badges. A button will be on that repeater that says "Assign Badge" if they don't already have the badge or "Remove Badge" if they do?